# Shoot, Shoot At

Tags: word-difference, prepositional-phrases

I have a question about the difference between the verb "*shoot*" and "*shoot at*":

> 1. Police ***shot*** the suspect.
> 2. Police ***shot at*** the suspect.

Are they just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are **not the same**.  Adding "at" implies intent, while the other just states fact (with minimal implications).  This is how I see it as someone with an almost Texan dialect.

> The police shot the suspect.

This is pretty straightforward.  The police fired bullets that actually struck the suspect.  All that matters is that bullets from the police hit the suspect.  For all we know, they could be been firing blindly or even accidentally.  Of course, the most common reason would be the police were trying to shoot the suspect and succeeded, and further context would probably be built to show the police's intent.  But by itself, this sentence says nothing more than the fact that police bullets hit the suspect.

> The police shot **at** the suspect.

This sentence shows that the police took aim before firing, and that they shot toward the suspect (likely to hit the suspect).    It does not record whether they actually did hit the suspect.  Without any other context, we only know what the police were trying to do.  For all we know, they aimed at the suspect, but missed (or even hit someone else).

Comment: There is no requirement of intent to hit. "I fired a shot at him but I made sure it went wide."

Comment: I would prefer a different preposition (or even a different phrase entirely) in that case.  Such as "I fired a warning shot toward him, but I made sure to miss."

Comment: It doesn't matter what you would prefer. There is no implication of intent.

Comment: @Catija Fine, I'll update the answer.  At definitely implies intent.  But I'll soften it up so it's only intentional aim, but not necessarily to hit.  Perhaps we're disagreeing because of dialectical/regional differences.

Comment: @Catija: Do you have a reference for your assertion? To me (native BrEng speaker) "shoot at" implies an intent to hit...

Comment: @psmears Do you have a reference to yours? I'd certainly agree that it *often* implies intent to hit but my example above is certainly an acceptable use.

Comment: @Catija: I'm only asserting that that's what the phrase means *to me*, for which my word should hopefully be good enough :) You appear to be asserting that *everyone* else is wrong and that this usage is *absolutely* generally acceptable. You may well be right, but if so it seems it should be easy enough to come up with a reference (or just a number of usage examples from reputable sources where it's clear from context that the "at" means "in the general direction of but explicitly without intent to hit") - and this would, to my mind, improve the quality of answers here :)

Comment: @psmears This is not my answer. You could just as rightly ask the OP of this answer to support his assertion that it **must** be used with the implication of intent. I included an example sentence in my original comment to show an obvious case of "shoot at" **not** implying intent. Do you disagree with my example?

Comment: @psmears I already edited my answer to show that I agree that it doesn't necessarily (just mostly) imply intent to actual hit, but only intentional aim.  It's a small distinction that probably doesn't come up often but the counterexample Catija proposed is valid.

Comment: @Catija: I know this is not your answer - I was responding to your comments, which are on *this* answer :) Yes, I do disagree with your example - if you made sure it went wide, you weren't firing *at* him (you were firing at a point somewhere beside him); I'd prefer an alternative like the one ryanyuyu suggested. This may be a regional/dialect thing though.

Comment: I notice that all of the examples in the comments on this answer use "shot" as a noun _(e.g. "I fired a shot at him"),_ which may contribute to the confusion. In the question and in the answer itself, "shot" is used as a past tense verb, so it should probably be used that way in these comments too.

Answer (score 19):

No, they're not the same.

> Police shot the suspect.

This means that the person was actually shot. They were injured or killed by a bullet fired from a gun.

> Police shot *at* the suspect.

This means that police shot *in the direction of* the suspect but did not necessarily actually hit them. This is appropriate to use if it's unknown whether the suspect was hit or not, or when it's known that the suspect was not hit.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Is it really that wrong to say: "I shot a tree." or "The tree was shot."? What would you say in those cases? "I hit a tree by shooting at it." and "The tree was hit by a bullet." perhaps?

Comment: I agree with @PJvG. Also, "shot" can refer to the ammunition itself: "The bullet was shot from the gun." or "The arrow was shot at the target." For that matter, "Police shot the suspect." _could_ be interpreted as "Police shot the suspect (out of a cannon)." though probably only pedantically.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That's not an idea I've heard before and I can't find any dictionary that confirms it.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich There is nothing about "shot" that requires it be a person or animal: "I shot the bottle and it exploded, throwing glass everywhere". This is perfectly fine.

Comment: OK, so I was wrong, deleted my comment...